# Play recorded audio with chronometer counter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a recorder app with chronometer counter, the chronometer is working fine with start record, stop record and stop play.

My problem is only with start play, when pressing start play button, the chronometer start from 0 but I couldn't stop the chronometer when the audio file stops.

This is the start play code, please help. Any help I greatly appreciated

```
playAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

            stopRecord.setEnabled(false);
            startRecord.setEnabled(false);
            stopAudio.setEnabled(true);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioSavePathInDevice);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!running) {
                myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
                 myChronometer.start();
                running = true;

                // myChronometer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();



            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Playing",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Sir, this the code of stop audio

```
stopAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (running) {
                myChronometer.stop();
                myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                pauseOffset = 0;
                pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
                running = false;
            }

            stopRecord.setEnabled(false);
            startRecord.setEnabled(true);
            stopAudio.setEnabled(false);
            playAudio.setEnabled(true);


            if(mediaPlayer != null){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
             //   MediaRecorderReady();

                //resetmymyChronometer
                myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                pauseOffset = 0;

            }
        }
    });
```

this is the code of stop record

```
stopRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (running) {
                myChronometer.stop();
                myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                pauseOffset = 0;
                pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
                running = false;
            }
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            stopRecord.setEnabled(false);
            playAudio.setEnabled(true);
            startRecord.setEnabled(true);
            stopAudio.setEnabled(false);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

MediaRecorderReady method

```
public void MediaRecorderReady(){
        //myChronometer start
        if (!running) {

            myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
            myChronometer.start();
            running = true;
        //***********************

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);

    }
}
```

startRecord Listener

```
startRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(checkPermission()) {

                AudioSavePathInDevice =
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";

                MediaRecorderReady();

                try {
                    startRecord.setEnabled(true);
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                startRecord.setEnabled(false);
                stopRecord.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post the code of your stopButton's onClick callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OnCompletionListener, for example:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // your code to stop record
    }
});
```

for more information :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener

Comment: how I can use this listener, please

Comment: It's called when the end of a media source is reached during playback , so you can use it after you initialize MediaPlayer , and put your code to stop the chrono into onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) [mp parameter : the MediaPlayer that reached the end of the file]

Comment: Sir, how I can display the audio file location to share it?

Comment: you have in your code : AudioSavePathInDevice =
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";

Comment: String audioSavePathInDevice = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + audioSavePathInDevice );
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*"); //or share.setType("audio/3gp");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));

Comment: Sir, when I press play button multiple time the voice is repeated, how I can fix this please

Comment: thank you very much for the code, but when I'm trying to share the file I get this message, the file format is not supported, would you please help.

Comment: I tried Sir, it's not working by just changing the extension

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
myChronometer.stop();
```

is never called.

In your playAudio's onClick() method, you should set

```
running = true
```

Comment: That's an other problem.

Comment: No it is not, you just check for running value

Comment: Sir, in playAudio I called (MediaRecorderReady) and there is running = true, SORRY i didn't mention it in my question, question updated

Comment: Based on the code you posted, MediaRecorderReady() is not called in playAudio's onClick, only in stopAudio's

Comment: Again, if you only click the playAudio button, your running flag is never set to true

Comment: I add the flage to  playAudio

Comment: and does the chronometer stops when you hit stopAudio button ?

Comment: yes, it's completely stop and the new value is 00:00, I removed the comment sing in (myChronometer.start();) on playAudio

Comment: it's not solved Sir, when I run the app, and pressing the play audio button, the audio stoped but chronometer still running, I want when the audio stop the chronometer stop also